# Javascript Execute Block of Codes

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to execute block of codes in javascript?
for example

```
status && { let i = 1; i = i + 3; console.log(i) };
```

Comment: no, but you can do an IIFE instead: `status && (_ => stuff)()`

Comment: what should happen? it looks more like half used `for` statement.

Comment: any relevant reason for not using a regular if statement instead? `&&` as shown in your example is usually next to an IIFE.

Comment: well i knew about using IIFE, im just curious knowing if there is such thing in js because Kotlin language has such.

Comment: @myckhel Hovering over the downvote button lists reasons why people generally give downvotes. "_This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful_".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a statement:

```
if (status) {
  let i = 1;
  i = i + 3;
  console.log(i);
}
```

If you absolutely need to run a block of statements where an expression is required syntactically, wrap them in an IIFE. [`do` expressions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-do-expressions) are still an early-stage proposal only.